# One-handed Solitaire algorithm

Tags: javascript, game, playing-cards

My attempt at a simulation of [one-handed Solitaire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-Handed_Solitaire). Any comments welcome!

```
// Basic implementation of one handed solitaire by Andrew Ewen.
//
// Not sure if working correctly as it wins roughly 1/90 games whereas wikipedia states it 
// is closer to 1/140.

function Card (suit, rank) {
    this.suit = suit;
    this.rank = rank;
}

Card.suits = ["Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds"];
Card.prototype.toString = function () {
    var suit = Card.suits[this.suit];
    var rank = (this.rank + 1).toString();

    switch (this.rank) {
        case 0:
            rank = "Ace";
            break;
        case 10:
            rank = "Jack";
            break;
        case 11:
            rank = "Queen";
            break;
        case 12: 
            rank = "King";  
            break;
    }   

    return rank + " of " + suit;    
}

function debugLog(msg) {
    var enabled = false;
    if (enabled) console.log(msg);
}

var deck = function () {
    cards = [];
    // Create deck of cards
    for (var suit = 0; suit < 4; suit++) {
        for (var rank = 0; rank < 13; rank++) {
            cards.push(new Card(suit, rank));
        }
    }   

    // Shuffle cards (Fisher-Yates)
    for (var i = cards.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
        var t = cards[j];
        cards[j] = cards[i];
        cards[i] = t;
    }
    return cards;
};

// Stats
var wins = 0;
var losses = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    var pile = deck();
    var hand = [];
    var discard = [];

    var turns = 0;
    var gameOver = false;
    while (!gameOver) {
        debugLog("turn: " + turns++);

        Array.prototype.push.apply(hand, pile.splice(pile.length - 1, 1));
        // Keep drawing cards until there is either non left or we have enough
        while (hand.length < 4 && pile.length > 0) {
            hand.push(pile.pop());
        }

        // Check if we're on our last 2 cards.
        var last2 = hand.length < 4;
        // Always check last card in hand
        var cardA = hand[hand.length - 1];
        // If we're on the last two compare with the first, otherwise compare 
        // with 4th from the end.
        var cardB = last2 ? hand[0] : hand[hand.length - 4];

        // Check for matches and discard accordingly
        var match = false;
        if(cardA.suit === cardB.suit) {
            var removed;
            if (last2) {
                removed = hand.splice(0, hand.length);
            } else {
                removed = hand.splice(hand.length - 3, 2);
            }
            Array.prototype.push.apply(discard, removed);
            match = true;
        } else if (cardA.rank === cardB.rank) { 
            var removed;
            if (last2) {
                removed = hand.splice(0, hand.length);
            } else {
                removed = hand.splice(hand.length - 4, 4);
            }
            Array.prototype.push.apply(discard, removed);
            match = true;
        }   

        if (match) { debugLog("Match: " + cardA + " -> " + cardB); }

        debugLog("hand: " + hand.length);
        debugLog("pile: " + pile.length);
        debugLog("discard: " + discard.length);
        debugLog("");

        // Detect win and loss conditions
        if (pile.length === 0 && !match) {
            debugLog("You lose...");
            losses += 1;
            gameOver = true;
        }
        if (pile.length === 0 && hand.length === 0) {
            debugLog("You win!");
            wins += 1;
            gameOver = true;
        }
    }
    console.log("Win rate: " + (wins/losses));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overall it's pretty good, but there might be something iffy going on with the rules you use.

I had honestly never heard of one-handed solitaire, but if I understand it correctly, there are no special rules for the last cards. You either have exactly 4 cards left, and win if you can discard them all, or you lose.

But you have a `last2` rule, where you change the rules to look at the 1st and *2nd* card if there are less than four cards left. I imagine this skews the results.

Anyway, in terms of code:

- Don't mix plain `console.log` and a custom logging function.
- Put the code for playing 1 round into a function. Right now it's all inside a loop that runs 10000 times. It'd be a lot simpler to just call `play()` and get a won/lost boolean back. You can always loop *that*.
- It'd be simpler to `unshift` cards onto the hand. Then you'd always be comparing `hand[0]` to `hand[3]` instead of having to subtract stuff from `hand.length`. Splicing also becomes just `splice(0, 4)` or `splice(1, 2)`
- You can use `concat` instead of `Array.prototype.push.apply` (or the slightly shorter alternative `[].push.apply`). The difference, however, is that `concat` returns a new array instead of modifying the receiver like `push` does.
- You can simplify `Card` and `Deck` a little by using a list of values for rank as well as suit:

  ```
  function Card(suit, rank) {
    this.suit = suit;
    this.rank = rank;
  }

  Card.prototype = {
    toString: function () {
      return this.rank + this.suit;
    }
  };

  Card.suits = ["♠︎", "♥︎", "♣︎", "♦︎"];
  Card.ranks = ["A", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "J", "Q", "K"];


  function Deck() {
    var cards, shuffled, i;

    cards = Card.suits.reduce(function (cards, suit) {
      return cards.concat(Card.ranks.map(function (rank) {
        return new Card(suit, rank);
      }));
    }, []);

    shuffled = [];
    while(cards.length) {
      i = Math.random() * cards.length | 0;
      shuffled.push(cards.splice(i, 1)[0]);
    }

    return shuffled;
  }
  ```

  I've named `Deck` with `PascalCase` as though it's a constructor, which it isn't quite. But you can call it as `new Deck` or just `Deck()` and either thing'll work, as it explicitly returns something.

You could also take a different tack altogether. You don't really need a `hand` array: You can just examine the shuffled deck directly. For instance:

```
function play() {
  var deck = new Deck,
      i = deck.length,
      a, b;

  while(true) {
    // decrement if we're too close to the end of the deck
    i = Math.min(i, deck.length-4);

    // if we had to decrement past zero, game's over
    if(i < 0) {
      return deck.length === 0;
    }

    // the cards to examine
    a = deck[i],
    b = deck[i+3];

    // match cards or decrement
    if(a.rank === b.rank) {
      deck.splice(i, 4);
    } else if(a.suit === b.suit) {
      deck.splice(i + 1, 2);
    } else {
      i--;
    }
  }
}
```

(Edit: I updated the code based on @Jonah's comment below to examine the deck from the end, rather than the beginning.)

Running 300,000 games, I get a 0.730% chance of winning, which is pretty close to 1 in 140.

Edit: It makes for a nice animation - see snippet below

```js
var frameTime = 100;
var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
var span = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];

function Card(suit, rank) {
  this.suit = suit;
  this.rank = rank;
}

Card.suits = ["♠︎", "♥︎", "♣︎", "♦︎"];
Card.ranks = ["A", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "J", "Q", "K"];


function Deck() {
  var cards, shuffled, i;
  
  cards = Card.suits.reduce(function (cards, suit) {
    return cards.concat(Card.ranks.map(function (rank) {
      return new Card(suit, rank);
    }));
  }, []);
  
  shuffled = [];
  while(cards.length) {
    i = Math.random() * cards.length | 0;
    shuffled.push(cards.splice(i, 1)[0]);
  }
  
  return shuffled;
}

function play() {
  var deck = new Deck,
      i = deck.length - 4;
  
  button.disabled = true;
  span.innerHTML = "";
  
  function step() {
    var a, b;
    
    i = Math.min(i, deck.length - 4);
    drawState(deck, i);
    
    if(i < 0) {
      if(deck.length) {
        span.innerHTML = "Lost (" + deck.length + " cards remain)";
      } else {
        span.innerHTML = "Won!";
      }
      button.disabled = false;
      return;
    }

    a = deck[i];
    b = deck[i+3];
    
    if(a.rank === b.rank) {
      deck.splice(i, 4);
    } else if(a.suit === b.suit) {
      deck.splice(i+1, 2);
    } else {
      i--;
    }
    
    setTimeout(step, frameTime);
  }
  
  step();
}

function drawState(deck, offset) {
  var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0],
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  
  canvas.width = 520;
  canvas.height = 35;
  
  function drawTriangle(x, y) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    ctx.lineTo(x + 3, y + 5);
    ctx.lineTo(x - 3, y + 5);
    ctx.closePath()
    ctx.fill();
  }
  
  if(offset >= 0) {
    drawTriangle(offset * 10 + 5, 25);
    drawTriangle((offset + 3) * 10 + 5, 25);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)";
    ctx.fillRect(offset * 10, 0, 40, 22);
  }
  
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
  ctx.font = "10px serif";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  
  deck.forEach(function (card, x) {
    x = x * 10 + 5;
    ctx.fillText(card.rank, x, 10);
    ctx.fillText(card.suit, x, 20);
  });
}


button.addEventListener("click", play, false);
play();
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<br>
<button>Play again</button>
<span></span>
```

Comment: Love the animation!  One small point: It might make the `while` loop a tad cleaner to start `i` at `deck.length`, then decrement it until it is at least 4 away from the end during each iteration, then do the mutations, if any, and if there aren't, decrement it once more.  The game ends when it's less than 0.  You'd avoid having to do the `Math.max` check this way.

Comment: @Jonah Thanks. And yeah, that'd help, you're right. Should've done that. Can't fix it right now, though, but I might update the code later.

Comment: @Jonah Welp, found time for it anyway, and have updated the code :)

Comment: Very nice.  I like the gray current hand box you added to the animation, too.  Wish I could upvote again.

Comment: I've fixed the winning with two cards problem. I think I misunderstood the game. Does make it a little bit fairer though!

Comment: Really nice animation and implementation by the way.

Comment: @andy1633 Thanks. As for the 2 card rule: Nobody ever said it _should_ be fair :) A rule for exactly 2 remaining cards would (using data from the 300,000 runs I did) still only come into play in 4.58% of games. And of those games, fewer still would actually be won. It'd certainly improve the odds of winning, but you'd still be losing the vast, vast majority of games. So it wouldn't help _that_ much, I don't think.